# Поиск подстрок с помощью регулярных выражений java

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток!

Делаю обработчик текста, необходимо применить регулярные выражения для поиска подстрок в строке, затем окрасить их и обратно вставить в webView.
Все работает, кроме регулярок.
Потратил уже дней 5 на гугление и составление своих вариантов.

Имеется строка `mText`. В ней сплошной текст с цифрами, кириллицей, латиницей и символами разными.

Нужно написать регулярное выражение, которое сможет находить текст вида

`// здесь комментарий (цифра 5, к примеру) *pnm текст <br>`

Вот такого формата подстроки нужно находить. Использовал регулярное `//.*<br>`, ищет все, но, если встречает круглую скобку или звездочку, то пропускает сразу же. Почему так ? Я же написал, что любой символ любое количество раз может встречаться -> `.*`.

Мой код для демонстрации "прогресса".

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("//.*<br>").matcher(mText);
        if (m.find()) {
            mText = mText.replaceAll(m.group(), "<font color=\"green\">" + m.group() + "</font>");
        }
```

Comment: Вы в HTML это ищете?.. Если да, то надо парсеры типа JSOUP пользовать, а регулярки ни в коем случае не применять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет. Ищу в тексте, который прочитан из *.txt файла, потом отформатирован тегами html и отображен в webView. Этакая подсветка синтаксиса/слов/текста получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `String.replaceAll` первым параметром принимает регулярное выражение, а во втором параметре можно использовать подстановки.

```java
String mText = 
      "int n = 6; // объявление переменной n типа int и присваивание ей значения 6<br>\n"
    + "int *pn = malloc(sizeof(int)); // объявление указателя pn и выделение под него памяти<br>\n"
    + "*pn = 5; // разыменование указателя и присваивание значения 5.<br>\n"
    + "n = *pn; // присвоить n то значение (5), на которое указывает pn<br>\n"
    + "free(pn); // освободить занятую память<br>\n"
    + "pn = &n; // присваивает указателю pn адрес переменной n(указатель будет ссылаться на n)<br>\n"
    + "n = 7; // *pn тоже стало равно 7<br>\n"
    + "<br>\n"
    + "// здесь комментарий (цифра 5, к примеру) *pnm текст <br>\n"
    + "int q = 6; // здесь комментарий (цифра 5, к примеру) *pnm текст <br>\n";


final String pattern = "(//.*?)<br>"; // текст от "//" до первого "<br>"

System.out.println( mText.replaceAll( pattern, "<font color=\"green\">$1</font><br>") );
```

Вывод:

```html
int n = 6; <font color="green">// объявление переменной n типа int и присваивание ей значения 6</font><br>
int *pn = malloc(sizeof(int)); <font color="green">// объявление указателя pn и выделение под него памяти</font><br>
*pn = 5; <font color="green">// разыменование указателя и присваивание значения 5.</font><br>
n = *pn; <font color="green">// присвоить n то значение (5), на которое указывает pn</font><br>
free(pn); <font color="green">// освободить занятую память</font><br>
pn = &n; <font color="green">// присваивает указателю pn адрес переменной n(указатель будет ссылаться на n)</font><br>
n = 7; <font color="green">// *pn тоже стало равно 7</font><br>
<br>
<font color="green">// здесь комментарий (цифра 5, к примеру) *pnm текст </font><br>
int q = 6; <font color="green">// здесь комментарий (цифра 5, к примеру) *pnm текст </font><br>
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, все также пропускает подстроки со скобками и символом звездочка.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы неправильно поняли мой ответ. Ваша проблема не в неправильной регулярке, а в использовании `String.replaceAll`. Ваша регулярка корректно находит строку со скобочками и прочим, отдает ее в вызове `m.group()`. Дальше вы используете эту строку в первом параметре `replaceAll`, который ожидает регулярку и интерпретирует скобки и звездочки соответственно. Поэтому вам надо или использовать `replace(m.group()...` (первая часть кода), или `replaceAll` с изначальной регуляркой и подстановками (вторая часть кода).

Comment: Использую Ваш код: http://mepic.ru/view/?id=d5b628d1dd1482a945a87abce89de59d . Работает он также, как и мой - красит только простой текст. Если есть латиница/скобка/или символ звездочки, то сразу же обходит стороной. Можно, конечно, добавить [a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9], но что делать со скобками и звездочкой ? || по сути Ваш код идентичен моему.

Comment: Пример текста, на котором не работает?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вот часть скриншота с экрана устройства, на которов производится отладка: http://mepic.ru/view/?id=9b15ab5df5f7ce7c8368f323ff21bd5c .

Comment: ну так все правильно: `m.find()` нашел первое попадание регулярки (m.group(1) возвращает первый коммент до конца строки), дальше реплейс заменил все вхождения первого коммента (строку "// объявление переменной n..."), и на этом все закончилось. Попробуйте либо по второму варианту, либо цикл сделайте, `find` может искать не с начала строки, а с произвольного места.

Comment: Без разницы, что я оставлю `m.group()`, что `m.group(1)`. Если прописать `m.group(2)`, то словлю ошибку `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4`

Comment: поменял ответ (символы)

Comment: Работает, в чем причина ? И как работает $1 внутри строки ? // будет здорово, если Вы добавить этот ответ в своей ответ [тавтология, извиняюсь]